# Выбрать конкретные одинаковые записи из всех строк используя IN

Tags: sql

Всем доброго времени не получается решить задачу в контексте предиката IN - Using following CTE write a query to select rows which have 'Yellow' in any of c1, c2, c3

```
with a(id, c1, c2, c3) as (values (1, 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue'), (2, null, 'Red', 'Green'), (3, 'Yellow', null, 'Violet'))
```

Есть такой код, но он найдет и другие повторяющиеся записи, а мне нужна конкретная - 'Yellow'

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    `table`
WHERE 
    `col1` IN (SELECT `col1` FROM `table` GROUP BY `col1` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY
    `col1`
```

И как обьяснить такой запрос?

```
SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 WHERE 1 NOT IN (2, NULL)
```

Comment: Что может быть тривиальнее? `WHERE 'Yellow' IN (c1, c2, c3)`

Comment: Спасибо, а я пытался наоборот впихнуть и ошибки получал... А как можно обьяснить этот запрос простыми словами? SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 WHERE 1 NOT IN (2, NULL)

Comment: @DiNewBie Допустим я не знаю SQL, однако этот язык простыми словами говорит что делать в базе данных. Что я сделал, я взял текст запроса, вставил его в онлайн переводчик(допустим я и английского не знаю) и получил вот такой забавный перевод: **ВЫБЕРИТЕ 1 ИЗ sysibm.sysdummy1, ГДЕ 1 ОТСУТСТВУЕТ В (2, NULL)** - это и будет ответом на ваш вопрос, как объяснить запрос )

Comment: @SwaD и в чем смысл его результата? зачем нужен этот запрос? мы ведь по факту ничего здесь не получаем

Comment: @DiNewBie А это к автору запроса. Сам запрос всегда будет возвращать 1, т.к. условие заведомо верное. Иногда так можно создавать более сложные конструкции where, например: where 1 = [select 1 from tab where x in [g, o]] допустим... поставил [ вместо скобки, что то ругается...

Comment: @SwaD я походу понял - При использовании NOT IN нужно соблюдать внимательностьб т.к. если какая либо строка из подзапроса возвращает null, то результат может не соответствовать ожиданиям

Comment: @SwaD *Сам запрос всегда будет возвращать 1, т.к. условие заведомо верное.* Садись, два. `1 NOT IN (2, NULL)` есть NULL.

Comment: @Akina Я еще хочу один вопрос задать, что бы не создавать лишний пост - что в моем коде не так? сам код должен найти отдел(ы) в которых не работают люди(их там нет). Вот собственно код SELECT workdept FROM employee a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee b WHERE b.workdept = a.workdept) - этот запрос исходя из задания нужно написать в "слепую" без CTE и таблиц. Я вот подумал если переносить его на реальную таблицу там ведь в графе имени будет стоять null?

Comment: Пожалуйста, одна тема - один вопрос. PS. Если честно, ЯННП.

Answer (score 0):

@DiNewBi Чтобы правильно сделать этот запрос, нужна таблица отделы, к который ты обратишься

```
Select deptno, deptname
From department
Where not Exists(Select * from employee where deptno = workdept)
```